# How to add an additional python package to the Pipfile of a docker-compose project (DJANGO)?

Tags: python, django, docker, pipenv

Good day everyone, hope you're doing really well. I would like to start this question by prefacing that I'm a real newbie when it comes to setting up projects in the right way. Right now I'm working on a Django app with a friend that already has some more experience with web development and he had already set up everything with Docker-compose, that is, we have containers for our Django app, MySQL, Celery, RabbitMQ, etc.

Now, I'm working on the back-end side of our project and need to add a new package to the list of packages the app container has: [Smart-Open](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/smart_open). The thing is, I have no idea how to do that. I'm on Windows, and using Git Bash to launch the docker-compose containers. What I've tried is opened the bash of the web app container and tried to pipenv install the module from there, but it was extremely slow, which made the Pipfile updating timeout:

```
$ winpty docker exec -it whs_webapp_1 bash
root@96caa176d252:/app/my_app_name# pipenv install smart_open[s3]
Creating a virtualenv for this project…
Using /usr/local/bin/python3.9 (3.9.6) to create virtualenv…
⠋Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/local/bin/python3.9
Using base prefix '/usr/local'
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py:1090: DeprecationWarning: the imp m
  import imp
New python executable in /root/.local/share/virtualenvs/my_app-NMSbRsZM/bi
Also creating executable in /root/.local/share/virtualenvs/my_app-NMSbRsZM
Installing setuptools, pkg_resources, pip, wheel...done.

Virtualenv location: /root/.local/share/virtualenvs/my_app-NMSbRsZM
Installing smart_open[s3]…
Collecting smart_open[s3]
  Using cached smart_open-5.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (57 kB)
Collecting boto3
  Downloading boto3-1.18.10-py3-none-any.whl (131 kB)
Collecting botocore<1.22.0,>=1.21.10
  Downloading botocore-1.21.10-py3-none-any.whl (7.8 MB)
Collecting s3transfer<0.6.0,>=0.5.0
  Downloading s3transfer-0.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (79 kB)
Collecting jmespath<1.0.0,>=0.7.1
  Using cached jmespath-0.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
Collecting python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1
  Downloading python_dateutil-2.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (247 kB)
Collecting urllib3<1.27,>=1.25.4
  Downloading urllib3-1.26.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (138 kB)
Collecting six>=1.5
  Using cached six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Installing collected packages: six, urllib3, python-dateutil, jmespath, botocore
Successfully installed boto3-1.18.10 botocore-1.21.10 jmespath-0.10.0 python-dat

Adding smart_open[s3] to Pipfile's [packages]…
Pipfile.lock (acbafc) out of date, updating to (9b92f3)…
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies…
Locking [packages] dependencies…
items())[0][1]
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/resolver.py", lin
    return {ireq: self.repository.get_hashes(ireq) for ireq in ireqs}
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/resolver.py", lin
    return {ireq: self.repository.get_hashes(ireq) for ireq in ireqs}
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/repositories/pypi
    return {
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/repositories/pypi
    self._get_file_hash(candidate.location)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/repositories/pypi
    for chunk in iter(lambda: fp.read(8096), b""):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/repositories/pypi
    for chunk in iter(lambda: fp.read(8096), b""):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/pip9/_vendor/requests/packa
    flush_decoder = True
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 135, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/pip9/_vendor/requests/packa
    raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, 'Read timed out.')
pip9._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnect
```

This command was running for about two hours until the timout happened. Can anyone explain to me how I exactly do I add this new package correctly? I can share our docker configuration, but I'm not sure what might be useful. Basically, what's the right way to add an additional package to the `pipfile` and have `pipfile.lock` update accordingly?

Thank you in advance for any help you may have. I've searched the internet but most guides do not seem to compare to the config we have, so I'm as confused as I can be.

Comment: You could get your docker build to lock your requirements. Take a read of this; https://pythonspeed.com/articles/pipenv-docker/

Comment: @markwalker, I believe this could work, but honestly the issue is that I have no idea how to run it inside Git Bash. If I try to do it the way I showed in the OP, it becomes extremely slow.

Comment: It's not completely clear what you're trying to do there. It looks like you're going into the container and then setting up a virtualenv or trying to lock the pip packages within the container. You don't want to do that, you need to get your packages installed when the container is built so it's already running them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your project directory contain a docker-compose.yml, a Dockerfile, and a requirements.txt file? If so, then the following steps might help.

Open your requirements.txt. You should see all of the python project dependencies listed here. For example, it might look like this initially:

```
Django==3.1.5
djangorestframework==3.12.2
```

Add smart-open as a requirement so that your requirements.txt looks something like:

```
Django==3.1.5
djangorestframework==3.12.2
smart-open
```

Now in order to update your image with this new package, you would need to rebuild the image. This is typically done as:

```
docker-compose up --build
```

Note: the above command will re-create the original image but with smart-open installed and will then spin up a container called whs_webapp_1 using this image.

To confirm that the package has been installed you can bash into the container and then open a python interactive terminal, by running the following command:

```
docker exec -it whs_webapp_1 bash 
python (or python3)
```

and testing that your package can be imported.

Comment: Thanks for the help, you were right I had to do this. But additionally, I also had to run `winpty docker-compose exec myapp pipenv install smart-open`. This seemed to re-create the Pipfile and Pipfile.lock with the new package included.